# How to generate a column based on matches over multiple columns in dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr

I am at loss on how to generate a new column with `dplyr` when using a conditional statement across multiple columns.

Given some data

```
library(dplyr)
 a <- data.frame(var1 = c("one", "two", "three"), var2 = c("three", "one", "three"), var3 = c("three", "two", NA))
```

```
> a
   var1  var2  var3
1   one three three
2   two   one   two
3 three three  <NA>
```

I would like to compute a new column matching a set of conditions (whether `"one"`, `"two"`, or `"three"` are present or not; if so, return an arbitrary value `1`, `2`, or `3`), in order of priority where `"one"` would have the highest priority and `"three"` the lowest (i.e., the returned vector should be `1 1 3`).

My way of approaching it would be

```
a %>%
mutate(new_variable = case_when(
             "one" %in% across(starts_with("var")) ~ 1,
             "two" %in% across(starts_with("var")) ~ 2,
             "three" %in% across(starts_with("var")) ~ 3,
             TRUE ~ NA))
```

This obviously doesn't work and I suspect it would search for a match the full three columns, if it did. Is there a way in `tidyverse` to do it?
Thanks!

Comment: Wouldn't the second value be "one"?

Comment: Whoops, yes, sorry. Fixed it!

Comment: Convert to numeric, take the `pmin` of those columns.

Comment: The values are arbitrary, sorry if the example is misleading

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A base R solution:

```
mapping <- c("one" = 1, "two" = 2, "three" = 3)

apply(a, 1, \(x) min(mapping[x], na.rm = TRUE))

#> [1] 1 1 3
```

Comment: This works just fine, but it handles `NA`s in a funny way (returning `Inf` in the full data if all cols have NAs)

Comment: @GiulioCentorame That's because `min(NULL)=Inf` (the reason should be clear once you note that `sum(NULL)=0`, `prod(NULL)=1` and `max(NULL)=-Inf`).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a `tidyverse` solution:

```
a %>%
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_longer(-id) %>%
  mutate(new_var = ifelse(value == "one", 1,
                          ifelse(value == "two", 2, 3))
         ) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarise(new_var = min(new_var, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  bind_cols(a, .) %>%
  select(-id)
   var1  var2  var3 new_var
1   one three three       1
2   two   one   two       1
3 three three  <NA>       3
```